# Interceptors in WCF data service

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

using ChangeInterceptors I can perform custom modifications on the objects currently being processed. Using QueryInterceptors I can only influence whether an object is returned by the wcf or not.
Is there a way to modify an object or a collection of objects after retrieving them via EF from the database and before sending them? The objects in question have navigation properties which are requested, too. So retrieving them via WebGet is not an option.

Any hints or ideas are highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had come across a similar requirement, and I found that WCF DS is very data-centric and limited when it comes to doing such things. You might want to look into [WCF DS Service Actions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2012/04/10/actions-in-wcf-data-services-part-1-service-author-code.aspx)
but I doubt that will address your requirement.

The solution I can think of is to retrieve your entities using a WebGet method, and then on the client use the `DataServiceQuery.Expand` to retrieve the navigation properties.